# IP messaging webhook is not triggered

Tags: c#, api, twilio

I'm using twilio ip messaging library for c#.
In admin page I have set some webhooks. When I use sample twilio mvc app, these webhooks work, but when I create a console app demo (create users and channel) the webhooks don't work.

```
var client = new IpMessagingClient(accountSid, authToken);
User user1 = client.CreateUser(serviceSid, "Tomas");
User user2 = client.CreateUser(serviceSid, "Lukas");

var channel = client.CreateChannel(serviceSid, channelType, "TESTTT", "");

client.CreateMember(serviceSid, channel.Sid, user1.Identity, roleChannelAdminSid);
client.CreateMember(serviceSid, channel.Sid, user2.Identity, roleChannelAdminSid);


client.CreateMessage(serviceSid, channel.Sid, user1.Identity, "Message1");
client.CreateMessage(serviceSid, channel.Sid, user2.Identity, "Message2");
```

Code works, because when I list some messages from this channel I can see these messages. Only it doesn't hit webhooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is explained in the [IP Messaging documentation for webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/webhooks):

> Only commands and events triggered from **clients** or **endpoints** will trigger the event callback (if configured). REST API calls will currently *not* trigger these.

(emphasis from the docs)

I believe this is to stop infinite loops of webhooks and messages from a server that ends up responding to itself over and over.

Comment: Thanks. So when i create token for specific user, can i get hook? Because i tried generate token and no response too.

Comment: Generating a token doesn't cause a request to the server. It's generated with your API secret which Twilio can verify independently when the token is used by a client/endpoint.

Comment: Yes, sry bad question, I thought when i create token for user and create message. like this: var clientUser = new IpMessagingClient(user1.AccountSid, Token(user1.Identity));
Method Token is from example twilio.

Comment: Oh I see. Again, no, when doing anything via the REST API the assumption is that your server, because it is doing the work, already knows what it is doing so can act upon that without the need for a webhook.